# Caliburn Micro - bind ListBox to property of objects in a collection

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I'm having trouble with binding the ItemsSource of a listbox to a collection of objects and then displaying a property of those objects as the list items.

My XAML code:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Class="CaliburnMicroBasic.ShellView"
    d:DesignWidth="358" d:DesignHeight="351">

<Grid Width="300" Height="300" Background="LightBlue">   
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfPeople}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding PersonName}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

My ViewModel:

```
namespace CaliburnMicroBasic {
using Caliburn.Micro;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;

public class ShellViewModel :  Screen, IShell
{
    public Person SelectedPerson{ get; private set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Person> ListOfPeople{ get; private set; }

    public ShellViewModel()
    {
        ListOfPeople = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
        ListOfPeople.Add(new Person("Name 1"));
        ListOfPeople.Add(new Person("Name 2"));
        ListOfPeople.Add(new Person("Name 3"));
        ListOfPeople.Add(new Person("Name 4"));
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string PersonName { get; private set; }

    public Person(string personName)
    {
        _personName = personName;
    }
}
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to have the listbox use Person.PersonName as the contents of each textblock in the listbox, but all I'm getting is four empty rows in the listbox. In other words, the listbox contains the correct number of items, but none of them are rendered correctly.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Just a tip for getting more data in these situations: check the debug output and see if you get some lines like "Cannot find source for binding with reference...". They can help you find the problem. You can also set the debug trace level to high on the databinding for even more info. See http://wpftutorial.net/DebugDataBinding.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are never assigning anything to your PersonName property. Change your code to:

```
   public Person(string personName)
    {
        this.PersonName  = personName;
    }
```

and remove your private field.